# using get_dummies() and OneHotEncoding on large number of Categorical Variable

Tags: python, machine-learning

In most of the Academic examples, we used to convert categorical features using `get_dummies()` or `OneHotEncoding()`. Lets say I want to use Country as a feature and in the dataset we have 100 unique countries. When we apply `get_dummies()` or `OneHotEncoding()` on country we will get 100 columns and model will be trained with 100 country columns + other features.

Lets say, we have deployed this model into production, and we received only 10 countries. When we pre-process the data by using `get_dummies()` or `OneHotEncoding()`, then model will fail predict because "Number of features model trained is not matching with the features passed" as we are passing 10 country columns + other features.

Can you please help me to understand how to handle such scenarios.How to deal with Large number of Categorical variables in multiple columns can be pre-process in the Model building.

Comment: the whole point is that you get the same features, or are able to make up-to the same features during production/testing. At test time, you dont just do the steps as if you were training, you do the steps to ensure you get back something that exactly matches training. As long as those 10 countries are a subset of 100, you can always fill the other 99 countries with 0s and the 1 country with 1, to get your 100 labels.

Comment: it means if the 10 Countries are subset of the 100 countries then their will not any issue in the prediction.

Comment: yes. Was that your question or no? are these 10 countries a subset?

Comment: yes, those 10 countries are subset, I was just wondering if this would work. I will run my model and will see if it goes well.Thanks A lot.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh -I have one more query, Say I did OneHotEncoding, Which convert one of my Categorical Columns to another 10 columns with binary values. Now I will trainf and test my model on this OneHotEncoded Data.
Now If I want to pass a new data, do I need to convert this new data first into OneHotEncoding and then fit my model to it??

Answer (score 2):

The `pandas.get_dummies()` function indeed should not be used in deployment, for the reason you described. The scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder, though, handles this situation just fine:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'country':['USA', 'Russia', 'China', 'Spain']})
X_test = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Russia', 'Ukraine', 'China', 'Russia']})
ohe.fit(X_train) 
ohe.transform(X_test).toarray()

array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

(Here I have set `handle_unknown='ignore'` so that new labels ('Ukraine') get encoded as all zeros. If you set `handle_unknown='error'` (which is the default), new labels will be raising errors.) So, the OneHotEncoder can handle a different set of labels in the test set.

Comment: So , it means if Test data has new entry(not a subset of the Train Data), then it will encoded as 0.Will it not affect my Model Accuracy?(Obviously because my model is not trained on this new entry right?) So I believe I need to add the possible entries in  to train.Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes, Aditya, you should do that if you can. (Sometimes your data just does not have all values which might occur in production. E.g. you are one-hot encoding car models and a new model appears on the market.)

Comment: I have one more query, Say I did OneHotEncoding, Which convert one of my Categorical Columns to another 10 columns with binary values. Now I will trainf and test my model on this OneHotEncoded Data.
Now If I want to pass a new data, do I need to convert this new data first into OneHotEncoding and then fit my model to it??